# Start application out of browser

Tags: javascript, html, browser

Is it possible to start a binary application (exe-programm) out of a browser (e.g. via JavaScript or HTML).

The browser runs on the same computer than the application is and both have the same user-ownership.

Thanks!

Comment: No, it's not possible to start any program from user computer using browser. You can't even access file system from it

Comment: maybe vbs script? but not from the browser

Comment: Your application can register a scheme, and the browser can then redirect to a URL using that scheme. The classic example is `mailto:`, which is often registered by email applications.